# Javascript Animated Skill Bar On Scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to activate all of this animations whenever I scroll to a certain section, in this case the second one.So basically it starts with the section one and whenever i reach the second one i want all of this to be activated. I've tried many things, but couldn't really figure out a way to solve this. Thanks in advance.

```css
.skills {
  padding: 4.8rem;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #ececec;
  max-width: 1440px;
  max-height: auto;
}

.skills-bar {
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 3.2rem;
  margin-top: 2.8rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  padding: 3rem 3.5rem;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  font-family: "Montserrat", Sans-serif;
}

.skills-bar .bar {
  margin: 2rem 0;
}

.skills-bar .bar:first-child {
  margin-top: 4.8rem;
}

.skills-bar .bar .info {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.skills-bar .bar .info span {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: showText 0.5s 1.5s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes showText {
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.skills-bar .bar .progress-line {
  position: relative;
  height: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ececec;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: left;
  box-shadow: inset 0xp 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05),
    0xp 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  animation: animate 1s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0.5, 1) forwards;
}

.bar .progress-line span {
  height: 100%;
  width: 80%;
  background: #9013fe;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: left;
  animation: animate 1s 1s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0.5, 1) forwards;
}

@keyframes animate {
  100% {
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}

.progress-line.html span {
  width: 90%;
}

.progress-line.css span {
  width: 85%;
}

.progress-line.js span {
  width: 70%;
}

.progress-line.react span {
  width: 20%;
}

.bar .progress-line span::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  right: 0;
  top: -12px;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border: 7px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
  border-right-width: 0px;
  border-top-color: #000;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: showText2 0.5s 1.5s linear forwards;
}

.bar .progress-line span::after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: -28px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  background: #000;
  padding: 1px 8px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: showText2 0.5s 1.5s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes showText2 {
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.progress-line.html span::after {
  content: "90%";
}

.progress-line.css span::after {
  content: "85%";
}

.progress-line.js span::after {
  content: "70%";
}

.progress-line.react span::after {
  content: "20%";
}

.skills-header {
  font-family: "Montserrat", Sans-serif;
}

.skills-list {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  row-gap: 2.4rem;
  margin-top: 9.2rem;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.skills-heading-secondary {
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
}

.skills-text {
  color: #495057;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<section class="section skills bar--hidden" id="section--2">
        <h2 class="skills-header heading-tertiary">Sklills</h2>
        <div class="skills-bar">
          <div class="bar">
            <div class="info">
              <span>HTML</span>
            </div>
            <div class="progress-line bar--hidden html"><span></span></div>
          </div>

          <div class="bar">
            <div class="info">
              <span>CSS</span>
            </div>
            <div class="progress-line css"><span></span></div>
          </div>

          <div class="bar">
            <div class="info">
              <span>JAVASCRIPT</span>
            </div>
            <div class="progress-line js"><span></span></div>
          </div>

          <div class="bar">
            <div class="info">
              <span>REACT</span>
            </div>
            <div class="progress-line react"><span></span></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

Comment: I can't see any code that you have tried. Please include what you have tried and describe what isn;t working.

Comment: Investigate IntersectionObserver, that will tell you when a certain element comes into or goes out of the viewport.